# How to get the intermediate results before hit the server using angular js

Tags: java, angularjs

Hi iam working in angular js . Here i want to get the intermediate results before hit the server using angular js please suggested me

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad. Do you have a more specific problem where we can start working on maybe?

Comment: I want the results before hit the server using angular js

Comment: How can you get results before hitting the server?

Comment: I mean i want intermediate results before hitting the server

Comment: If you add a small bit of code to your question, that might make it clearer what you're trying to do.

Comment: For exmaple I want to craete a tree like this way root node and subchilds in that mannaer i need to know before open the screen in mean  time it form a image how to do this